# Delete a specefic string in the textfile

Tags: powershell

Delete the only occurrence of "(123456789)" anywhere in a text file including both open and close parenthesis

```
get-content "D:\testing.txt" | % {$_ -replace "(\d{9})",""} | Out-File D:\temp\out.txt
```

Comment: you need to escape the parens.

Comment: It deletes all the numbers present somewhere else and deletes only numbers inside the paranthesis and does not delete the paranthesis

Comment: i repeat - you need to escape the parens if you want them to be part of the matched chars. otherwise they are considered regex grouping markers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect -> try `"\(\d{9}\)"`.

You can check your code via this statement:

```
'12 abc"(123456789)" 90 efg' -replace '"\(\d{9}\)"'
```

Output:

```
12 abc 90 efg
```

Above code is available only under this tio.run [link](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X93QSCExKVlJw9DI2MTUzNzCUlNJwdJAITUtXV1Btyi1ICcxOVVBXSlGIyal2rI2RlNJ/f9/AA).

Comment: I'm not sure which of the [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) gives access to the deleted answers, but a lot of users can see them. Consider editing the answer, rather than deleting and answering again. There are some restrictions if you delete often.

Comment: @Badukan, Thx didn't know about that.  Will keep it in mind for the future.